# Add CSS class to {{block type="cms/block" block_id="my_block1"}}

Tags: blocks

Add CSS class to {{block type="cms/block" block_id="my_block1"}}

This now outputs as `html here`, but I see widget block add a DIV tag around it with a CSS ID.

**Question**: How can we add a  tag around `block type="cms/block"` and echo some css class like the BlockId()

`<div class="cms-block my_block1">html here</div>` where `my_block1` is the block id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do that unless you want to overwrite template for it. Widget block and a DIV tag you are seeing are coming from default widget handler.

If all you want to add `css class` then how about this way? Wrapping with div?

```
<div class="cms-block my_block1">{{block type="cms/block" block_id="my_block1"}}</div>
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**

Check template file called `template/cms/widget/static_block/default.phtml`. This file is responsible for that DIV.

Comment: Yes this would work. Just find it strange that widget adds the div and block does not. Wondering where to override cms block to show same behavior

Comment: See my updated answer.